# Can't find Microsoft Internet Transfer Control in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, basic

New project in Visual Basic using Visual Studio 2013.

Want to add the "Microsoft Internet Controls" component but I can't find it.

What am I missing?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? It's possible the control you're looking for is ancient technology that has a modern replacement.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. Funnily I did google but didn't find that link. I am trying to code a simple ftp program. I was following a tutorial from vbtutor http://www.vbtutor.net/vb6/lesson34.html

Comment: Sometimes I hate Google.That entire tutorial is about VB6, which was obsolete over a decade ago. Do not ever use VB6, or anything related to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the second link on Google:
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-customize/cant-find-reference-to-microsoft-internet-controls/e138ff0c-8046-47b1-9c0c-ac28cebe3c7a

Apparently it may have been renamed "Microsoft Browser Helpers" and you may need to add a reference to "ieframe.dll".

---

If you need FTP, it is fully supported in the .NET framework. You could start with the examples on MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229718%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score -1):

The `inet1` Internet Transfer Control is installed with MS Office. Install it and you should have no problem having it become available to use in Visual Studio etc.

It's old but still completely useful in apps. It did all the FTP and HTTP calls for a web crawler I wrote years ago and was fast and completely error-free when crawling 100s of 1000s of web pages at a time while I slept. I'd use `inet1` today if I was writing an app that did huge amounts of internet calls as quickly as possible.